# How to convert a row of data to percent? R

Tags: r, dplyr

this is my data set.

```
print(data)

          Month.2020        Jan     Feb   Mar      Apr   May     Jun      Jul
1   1st of Month Count     4248   4413    4534    4634   4621   4424    3323
2   Monthly Difference      NA     +165   +121    +100   -13    -197    -1101
3   Monthly Percent Change  NA     0.038  0.027   0.022  -0.002 -0.043  -0.249
```

I want my output to be

```
          Month.2020        Jan     Feb   Mar      Apr   May     Jun      Jul
1   1st of Month Count     4248   4413    4534    4634   4621   4424    3323
2   Monthly Difference      NA     +165   +121    +100   -13    -197    -1101
3   Monthly Percent Change  NA     3.8%   2.7%    2.2%   -0.2%  -4.3%   -24.9%
```

i tried the following but it didn't work

```
data[3,2:8] <- apply(data[5:7,2:5]*100, 2, function(x) paste0(x, "%"))
```

And i tried specifying each "Cell" and it didn't work either

```
data[3,3] <- paste("3.8%")
```

Comment: `data[3:,3:8]<- sprintf("%0.2f",unlist(data[3,3:8])*100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[3,-c(1,2)] <- paste0(100*df[3,-c(1,2)],'%')

            Month.2020  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr   May   Jun    Jul
1      1stofMonthCount 4248 4413 4534 4634  4621  4424   3323
2    MonthlyDifference   NA  165  121  100   -13  -197  -1101
3 MonthlyPercentChange   NA 3.8% 2.7% 2.2% -0.2% -4.3% -24.9%

#Data
df <- structure(list(Month.2020 = c("1stofMonthCount", "MonthlyDifference", 
"MonthlyPercentChange"), Jan = c(4248L, NA, NA), Feb = c(4413, 
165, 0.038), Mar = c(4534, 121, 0.027), Apr = c(4634, 100, 0.022
), May = c(4621, -13, -0.002), Jun = c(4424, -197, -0.043), Jul = c(3323, 
-1101, -0.249)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I got this error; Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
6: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @FruityPebblePug Hi, I have added the data I used. It looks some of your variables are factors. Try to have a similar structure as `df` with numeric columns otherwise you will get error. Also do you have other variables in your original dataframe? Other than the ones posted here

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df[3, 2:8] <- sapply(df[3, 2:8], function(x) scales::percent(x, big.mark = 1, accuracy = 0.1))
```